# Google map location permission does not show up for Android version 8+ Android developement

Tags: android, google-maps, permissions

Google maps permission does not pop up for Android version 8+. For Android 5, it works fine.

The permission should pop up like the following picture, but it doesn't show on Android version 8+
Now, I know it has something to do with run-time permission. I added related code, but the app stops after I grant the permission.

What have I done wrong?

These are all the permissions granted.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

This is the code in onCreate()

```
 if (!checkPermission()) {
            requestPermission();
}
```

These are code related to permission checking and granting

```
 private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
    private void requestPermission() {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean fineLocationAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean coarseLocationAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (!(fineLocationAccepted && coarseLocationAccepted)) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                                showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                break;
        }
    }
    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

But the app crashes after I click on "allow".

[image]
[image]

Error messages

```
2019-05-01 23:46:17.257 4519-16175/? E/PhenotypeFlagCommitter: Retrieving snapshot for com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader failed
    java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1063)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1352)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:278)
        at asip.a(:com.google.android.gms@16091022@16.0.91 (040700-244116403):27)
        at alhm.a(:com.google.android.gms@16091022@16.0.91 (040700-244116403):2)
        at alhm.a(:com.google.android.gms@16091022@16.0.91 (040700-244116403):19)
        at alhm.a(:com.google.android.gms@16091022@16.0.91 (040700-244116403):29)
        at com.google.android.gms.clearcut.uploader.QosUploaderChimeraService.d(:com.google.android.gms@16091022@16.0.91 (040700-244116403):3)
        at com.google.android.gms.clearcut.uploader.QosUploaderChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@16091022@16.0.91 (040700-244116403):14)
        at com.google.android.gms.clearcut.uploader.QosUploaderChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@16091022@16.0.91 (040700-244116403):6)
        at zse.run(:com.google.android.gms@16091022@16.0.91 (040700-244116403):5)
        at rrt.b(:com.google.android.gms@16091022@16.0.91 (040700-244116403):32)
        at rrt.run(:com.google.android.gms@16091022@16.0.91 (040700-244116403):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at rxx.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: have you added checkpermission in your code

Comment: No. I didn't. So, I should add checkpermission for it to work on Android version 8+ ?

Comment: yes you have to add those things

Comment: can you add your code here'

Comment: Why it works on Android 5? I read something called run-time permission, is that a requirement for android 8+?

Comment: runtime permission are in android from android 6 and till you wont ask permssion and check for permission you will not get what you want

Comment: I have edited the question and added some code related to permission checking and requesting. But now facing app crashing problem. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did

```
 private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main2Activity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Main2Activity.this, permission)) {

                //This is called if user has denied the permission before
                //In this case I am just asking the permission again
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main2Activity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

            } else {
                deviceSetting(getApplicationContext());
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main2Activity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
            }
        } else {
            deviceSetting(getApplicationContext());
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void deviceSetting(Context context) {

        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000 / 2);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        Log.e("tag", "All location settings are satisfied.");
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        Log.e("tag", "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to upgrade location settings ");

                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                            // in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(Main2Activity.this, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.e("tag", "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog not created.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            deviceSetting(getApplicationContext());
        } else {
            saveData(latitude, longitude, "no");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("onActivityResult()", Integer.toString(resultCode));

        //final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK: {
                        // All required changes were successfully made
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location enabled by user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    }
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: {
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location not enabled, user cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {


        Log.e("inside", "startlocationupdate");
        // Create the location request to start receiving updates
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        //   mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        ///   mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        // Create LocationSettingsRequest object using location request
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
        Log.e("locationsettingsreuqest", String.valueOf(locationSettingsRequest));
        // Check whether location settings are satisfied
        // https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient
        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(Main2Activity.this);
        settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest);

        Log.e("locationsettingsreuqest", String.valueOf(settingsClient));
        // new Google API SDK v11 uses getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext()).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        onLocationChanged(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                    }
                },
                Looper.myLooper());
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
```

I hope it works otherwise let me know